# Implementation of Harris Corner Detector using Sobel and Gaussian Blur in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, corner-detection

I want to implement the harris corner detector. I found this page to be very helpful, since it shows how the detector is implemented using the basic opencv functions (like gaussianBlur and Sobel):
https://compvisionlab.wordpress.com/2013/03/02/harris-interest-point-detection-implementation-opencv/

Now I even want to implement Gaussian Blur and Sobel. If I run my Gaussian or Sobel over some Images it works but in combination with my Corner Detector it does not work. Can anybody help me please. The full Code is below, thx.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/// Global variables
Mat src, src_gray, dst;
int thresh = 200;
int max_thresh = 255;

char* source_window = "Source Image";
char* corners_window = "Corner Image";


/// Function header
void cornerHarris_demo(int, void*);
void cornerHarrisMe(int, int, double);
int xGradient(Mat, int, int);
int yGradient(Mat, int, int);
void SobelMe(Mat&,Mat&,int,int);
int borderCheck(int M, int x);
void SepGaussian(Mat&, Mat&, int, int);


/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /// Load source image and convert it to gray
    src = imread("data/a-real-big-church.jpg", 1);
    //Mat src_gray(src.size(), CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    /// Create a window and a trackbar
    namedWindow(source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    createTrackbar("Threshold: ", source_window, &thresh, max_thresh, cornerHarris_demo);
    imshow(source_window, src);

    cornerHarris_demo(0, 0);

    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}

/** @function cornerHarris_demo */
void cornerHarris_demo(int, void*)
{
    Mat dst_norm, dst_norm_scaled;

    /// Detector parameters
    int blockSize = 2;
    int apertureSize = 3;
    double k = 0.04;

    /// Detecting corners
    cornerHarrisMe(blockSize, apertureSize, k);
    /// Normalizing
    normalize(dst, dst_norm, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_32FC1, Mat());
    convertScaleAbs(dst_norm, dst_norm_scaled);

    /// Drawing a circle around corners
    for (int j = 0; j < dst_norm.rows; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dst_norm.cols; i++)
        {
            if ((int)dst_norm.at<float>(j, i) > thresh)
            {
                circle(dst_norm_scaled, Point(i, j), 5, Scalar(255), 2, 8, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    /// Showing the result
    namedWindow(corners_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(corners_window, dst_norm_scaled);
}

void cornerHarrisMe(int blockSize, int apertureSize, double k)
{
    Mat x2y2, xy, mtrace, x_der, y_der, x2_der, y2_der, xy_der, x2g_der, y2g_der, xyg_der;

    //1: calculate x and y derivative of image via Sobel
    SobelMe(src_gray, x_der, 1, 0);
    SobelMe(src_gray, y_der, 0, 1);
    //2: calculate other three images in M
    pow(x_der, blockSize, x2_der);
    pow(y_der, blockSize, y2_der);
    multiply(x_der, y_der, xy_der);
    //3: gaussain
    SepGaussian(x2_der, x2g_der, 1, 0);
    SepGaussian(y2_der, y2g_der, 0, 1);
    SepGaussian(xy_der, xyg_der, 1, 1);
    //4. calculating R with k
    multiply(x2g_der, y2g_der, x2y2);
    multiply(xyg_der, xyg_der, xy);
    pow((x2g_der + y2g_der), blockSize, mtrace);
    dst = (x2y2 - xy) - k * mtrace;
}

// gradient in the x direction
int xGradient(Mat image, int x, int y)
{
    return image.at<uchar>(y - 1, x - 1) +
        2 * image.at<uchar>(y, x - 1) +
        image.at<uchar>(y + 1, x - 1) -
        image.at<uchar>(y - 1, x + 1) -
        2 * image.at<uchar>(y, x + 1) -
        image.at<uchar>(y + 1, x + 1);
}

// gradient in the y direction
int yGradient(Mat image, int x, int y)
{
    return image.at<uchar>(y - 1, x - 1) +
        2 * image.at<uchar>(y - 1, x) +
        image.at<uchar>(y - 1, x + 1) -
        image.at<uchar>(y + 1, x - 1) -
        2 * image.at<uchar>(y + 1, x) -
        image.at<uchar>(y + 1, x + 1);
}

void SobelMe(Mat& source, Mat& destination, int xOrder, int yOrder){
    int gradX, gradY, sum;

    destination = source.clone();

    if (xOrder == 1 && yOrder == 0){
        for (int y = 1; y < source.rows - 1; y++){
            for (int x = 1; x < source.cols - 1; x++){
                gradX = xGradient(source, x, y);
                sum = abs(gradX);
                sum = sum > 255 ? 255 : sum;
                sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
                destination.at<uchar>(y, x) = sum;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (xOrder == 0 && yOrder == 1){
        for (int y = 1; y < source.rows - 1; y++){
            for (int x = 1; x < source.cols - 1; x++){
                gradY = yGradient(source, x, y);
                sum = abs(gradY);
                sum = sum > 255 ? 255 : sum;
                sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
                destination.at<uchar>(y, x) = sum;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (xOrder == 1 && yOrder == 1)
        for (int y = 1; y < source.rows - 1; y++){
            for (int x = 1; x < source.cols - 1; x++){
                gradX = xGradient(source, x, y);
                gradY = yGradient(source, x, y);
                sum = abs(gradX) + abs(gradY);
                sum = sum > 255 ? 255 : sum;
                sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;
                destination.at<uchar>(y, x) = sum;
            }
        }
}

int borderCheck(int M, int x){
    if (x < 0)
        return -x - 1;
    if (x >= M)
        return 2 * M - x - 1;
    return x;
}

void SepGaussian(Mat& source, Mat& desination, int sigmaX, int sigmaY){
    // coefficients of 1D gaussian kernel with sigma = 1
    double coeffs[] = { 0.0545, 0.2442, 0.4026, 0.2442, 0.0545 };
    Mat tempX, tempY;
    float sum, x1, y1;

    desination = source.clone();
    tempY = source.clone();
    tempX = source.clone();

    // along y - direction
    if (sigmaX == 0 && sigmaY == 1){
        for (int y = 0; y < source.rows; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < source.cols; x++){
                sum = 0.0;
                for (int i = -2; i <= 2; i++){
                    y1 = borderCheck(source.rows, y - i);
                    sum = sum + coeffs[i + 2] * source.at<uchar>(y1, x);
                }
                desination.at<uchar>(y, x) = sum;
            }
        }
    }

    // along x - direction
    else if (sigmaX == 1 && sigmaY == 0){
        for (int y = 0; y < source.rows; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < source.cols; x++){
                sum = 0.0;
                for (int i = -2; i <= 2; i++){
                    x1 = borderCheck(source.cols, x - i);
                    sum = sum + coeffs[i + 2] * source.at<uchar>(y, x1);
                }
                desination.at<uchar>(y, x) = sum;
            }
        }
    }

    // along xy - direction
    else if (sigmaX == 1 && sigmaY == 1){
        for (int y = 0; y < source.rows; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < source.cols; x++){
                sum = 0.0;
                for (int i = -2; i <= 2; i++){
                    y1 = borderCheck(source.rows, y - i);
                    sum = sum + coeffs[i + 2] * source.at<uchar>(y1, x);
                }
                tempY.at<uchar>(y, x) = sum;
            }
        }
        for (int y = 0; y < source.rows; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < source.cols; x++){
                sum = 0.0;
                for (int i = -2; i <= 2; i++){
                    x1 = borderCheck(source.cols, x - i);
                    sum = sum + coeffs[i + 2] * tempY.at<uchar>(y, x1);
                }
                desination.at<uchar>(y, x) = sum;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The Result:
[Here is the a picture of the Result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v34vW.jpg)

The Result is now the other way around, it detects areas where are no Corners.
In case there are some questions, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Your repeatedly appearing line `sum = sum < 0 ? 0 : sum;` seems odd as `sum` is only ever calculated from an `abs(X)` or `abs(X) + abs(Y)` so it can surely never be less than zero.